# Compilation error in the `glbinding` example, which is supposed to output the OpenGL version

Tags: c++, glfw, glbinding

I wanted to understand how the OpenGL loader library [`glbinding`](https://github.com/cginternals/glbinding) works, but I couldn't compile my very basic example, which is a reduced version of their `cubescape` example:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glbinding/glbinding.h>
#include <glbinding-aux/ContextInfo.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
  if (glfwInit())
  {
    // ------ create window
    auto const windowPtr = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "tc0001", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (windowPtr)
    {
      glfwHideWindow(windowPtr);
      glfwMakeContextCurrent(windowPtr);
      glbinding::initialize(glfwGetProcAddress, false);
      cout << "OpenGL Version:  " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::version() << endl;
      cout << "OpenGL Vendor:   " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::vendor() << endl;
      cout << "OpenGL Renderer: " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::renderer() << endl;
      // ------ destroy window
      glfwDestroyWindow(windowPtr);
    }
    else
    {
      cout << "glfwCreateWindow error" << endl;
    }
    glfwTerminate();
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "glfwInit error" << endl;
  }
}
```

The culprit is the line:

```
cout << "OpenGL Version:  " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::version() << endl;
```

The compiler complains about this line, and after that, as usual, outputs a lot of information about failed attempts to find a right implementation of the ‘operator<<’:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘glbinding::Version’)
```

What am I doing wrong?

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- Compiler: g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
- glbinding: 3.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly familiar with the OpenGL library, but from a C++ programming perspective the problem is caused by the fact you are trying to use cout to print a non-trivial type - in the case of `cout<<glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::version()`, it is class `glbinding::Version`.

You can use cout to print plain old data types like `int`, `double`, also `std::string`, but for more complex (i.e., arbitrary) classes you'll have to define what data fields of that class `cout` gets to print, and in what format.

Does the OpenGL library provide an overload definition of `operator<<` for class `glbinding::Version`?

If not, but you know the definition of class `glbinding::Version`, you just need to define an overload of `operator <<` for this class. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/overloading-the-io-operators/

Comment: Yes, I know.... However their example contains this line, plus a lot of additional includes, and my experiments with these includes didn't get me anywhere. I hoped somebody with `glbinding` intimate knowledge could help me. I even created this tag just now

Comment: @HEKTO I see. Sorry for the unhelpful answer. I think the problem is more likely caused by how you compile your example executable than a problem existing in the library - but I can't give more help since I'm no OpenGL user.

Answer (score 0):

The [`version()`](https://glbinding.org/docs/v2.0/classglbinding_1_1_context_info.html) method returns an object of type [`glbinding::Version`](https://glbinding.org/docs/v2.0/classglbinding_1_1_version.html) which cannot be automatically converted to a string. You need to use [`toString()`](https://glbinding.org/docs/v2.0/classglbinding_1_1_version.html#a08820ed3e603a11ddf913aa57e8d82d3):

<s>`cout << "OpenGL Version:  " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::version() << endl;`</s>

```cpp
cout << "OpenGL Version:  " << glbinding::aux::ContextInfo::version().toString() << endl;
```